# Smooth scroll to position in Android gridview makes work it wrong

Tags: android, gridview

I have an app which is loading the images from sdcard to gridview on my main screen. I have created ViewHolder so views was intantiating only once. It all worked well until I put `smoothScrollToPosition` method.

I call `smoothScrollToPosition` when activity is resuming or creating, so instantly user grid is scrolled to chosen position. The problem is that it loads images that are at the beginning of the grid.

Lets say I have GridView containing 20 grids. Only 2 have images, first and second, the others are empty (has default image set). Now on the activity start I want to scroll smoothly to 12 position. It should be empty, but 12 and 13 grid are containing images from first and second grid. This problem doesn't exist if there are already images to load on this grid.

My adapter is typical :

```
 public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    dayNumber = dayList.get(position).getDayId();
    imagePath = dayList.get(position).getPhotoPath();

    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.gridview_cell, parent, false);

        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.day = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.dayDateTextView);
        holder.image = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.dayImage);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    setDayNumber(dayNumber);
    setCurrentDay();
    setBitmap(imagePath, parent, position);

    return convertView;
}
```

I will be thankful for any help. Thanks

EDIT :

There is rest of the adapter :

```
private void setBitmap(String imagePath, ViewGroup parent, int position) {
    if (imagePath != null) {
        setBitmapFromSd(parent, position);
    } else {
        holder.image.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_action_camera);
    }
}

    private void setBitmapFromSd(ViewGroup parent, int position) {
    Bitmap bitmap = getBitmapFromMemCache(imagePath);
    if (bitmap != null) {
        holder.image.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    } else {
        BitmapWorkerTask task = new BitmapWorkerTask(holder.image, parent, this, dayList.get(position));
        task.execute(imagePath);
    }
}
```

And this is BitmapWorkerTask :

```
public BitmapWorkerTask(ImageView imageView, ViewGroup parent, PhotoAdapter photoAdapter, Day day) {
    imageViewReference = new WeakReference<ImageView>(imageView);
    this.photoAdapter= photoAdapter;
    this.parent = parent;
    this.day = day;
}

protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... path) {
    Bitmap bitmap = null;
    try {
        bitmap = PhotoUtils.decodeSampledBitmapFromFile(parent, path[0]);
        photoAdapter.addBitmapToMemoryCache(path[0], bitmap);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        dbAdapter.setDayImage(null, day.getDayId(), day.getMonthId(), day.getYearId());
    }
    return bitmap;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {
    if (imageViewReference != null && bitmap != null) {
        final ImageView imageView = imageViewReference.get();
        if (imageView != null) {
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you using a library for downloading the images?

Comment: No, simple `BitmapFactory.decodeFile(currentPhotoPath, options);`. The only library I am using is `stickygridheaders`.

Comment: Can you post the rest of getView method? specially where you set the image resources

Comment: @hoomi, I have edited main question

Comment: Do you have onPostExecute in your BitmapWorkerTask? I am guessing you are updating the imageview in there.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I have edited my answer to show whole BitmapWorkerTask.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that you do something like this:

1. In `getView` method you 'holder.image.setTag(imagePath);`
2. Add another field to `BitmapWorkerTask` and call it `imagePath`
3. Add `this.imagePath = path[0];` in `doInBackground`
4. In `onPostExecute` method you add the following lines:

   ```
   if (imageView != null) {
       String imagePath = (String)imageView.getTag();
       if (imagePath.equals(this.imagePath) {
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);    
       }
   }
   ```

I hope that this resolves your issue

Comment: Thanks, I have tried this, but unfortunately its still not working. The only solution for now it is to remove smoothScroll method... It looks like this `smoothScrollToPosition` messes the position id structure in adapter.